# Binning NMR data in R

Tags: r, binning

I've imported NMR spectra on R as .csv file ( first column represent the ppm values the others,  signal intensity for various spectra) and I would like to bin the data, let's say, make every 5 points one. Any suggestions?

Cheers,

Marcelo

Comment: I've never worked with NMR data per se, so a fake, minimal yet working example would come a long way. BTW, you're probably looking for `cut`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Marcelo, you can look at ChemoSpec on GitHub here:  https://github.com/bryanhanson/ChemoSpec

The function binBuck will do what you ask.  There is a fairly complete vignette available once you have the package installed.

To use ChemoSpec, you may have to import your data set differently than you apparently currently have it, or if you have the skills you can modify what you have now.  Again, the vignette explains how ChemoSpec stores the data.

Let me know if you need further assistance.  Bryan

Comment: Bryan, I'm having a hard time creating the "spectra" using the "getManyCsv", how do I have to set up my csv files in order to get it to work? thanks!\

Comment: @Marcelo Each csv should have the same two columns: col 1 should be the shifts, col 2 the peak heights/intensities.  The files should not have a col header.  One file per spectrum, all in the same directory, and no other csv's in that directory.  And file names should reflect the sample name/group: "control_1.csv" for example; then use "control" as part of gr.crit.  Contact me at hanson@depauw.edu going forward and we'll get it running!  Bryan

Comment: Bryan, thanks for the tip. I finally figure out how to arrange my files! I was trying to import all at once but it wasn't working.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old question, but it can be useful for other users.
You can use "prospectr" package in R through function "binning". You can set "bin" as your final spectral size or "bin.size" for as ratio.